# Installing Windows-10 on my Laptop running UBUNTU

Tags: windows

I am running UBUNTU 16.04 presently on my laptop. I want to install Win-10 on this machine as some specific software are available only on Win platform. I have the Windows-10 ISO file but I am not able to install it. So please provide procedure for installing Windows-10 on UBUNTU machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would help you out quite well: [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Or more correctly MBR or gpt. Windows only installs in BIOS mode to MBR partitioned drives and must use a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode from gpt partitioned drives. And you need to install Windows in same boot mode as Ubuntu, but if Ubuntu is BIOS mode on gpt you need to convert Ubuntu to UEFI boot if hardware is UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cat and oldfred for your response.

But the procedure was a bit complicated and not properly explained. So if you can please give an easy or well described process it will help.

Thx in advance.

Regards,
Kumar